# one line if-else

Tags: php, if-statement

An easy question for you guys.
I assume there must be an easier (= less code) way to do the following snippet:

```
if (link_validate_url($items[0]['url_value'])) {
} else {
    form_set_error('', 'Not a valid URL.');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply negate the return value using the `!` operator:

```
if (!link_validate_url($items[0]['url_value'])) {
    form_set_error('', 'Not a valid URL.');
}
```

Of course you could shorten it even more, but IMO that reduces the readability:

```
if (!link_validate_url($items[0]['url_value']))
    form_set_error('', 'Not a valid URL.');
```

or even

```
if (!link_validate_url($items[0]['url_value'])) form_set_error('', 'Not a valid URL.');
```

Comment: That easy, really? :) Ok, this is nice! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (! link_validate_url($items[0]['url_value'])) {
    form_set_error('', 'Not a valid URL.');
}
```

Also, you might want to [read this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Comment: Thanks for the link and info!

Answer (score 1):

You could (ab)use the ternary operator.

Typically it is `condition ? action if true : action if false;` But you can leave actions blank.

This leaves you with:

`link_validate_url($items[0]['url_value'] ?: form_set_error('', 'Not a valid URL.');`

**Edit:**

This is PHP 5.3+

[Notes on this operator can be found here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!link_validate_url($items[0]['url_value'])) {
   form_set_error('', 'Not a valid URL.');
}
```

or you can (ab)use common compiler optimization that the second part of an or is never executed if the first part is true

```
link_validate_url($items[0]['url_value']) or form_set_error('', 'Not a valid URL.');
```